# Javascript array of TextBlock elements from Xaml file

Tags: javascript, silverlight, xaml

A working xaml file (Silverlight) has a lot of TextBlock elements. I need those for data manipulation, so I want to put them in a global array:

```
var textBlockArray = [];

function fillDataArray() {
    textBlockArray = document.getElementsByTagName("TextBlock");
}

function OnLoaded() {
    alert('In Vowels');
    fillDataArray();
}
```

textBlockArray.length is 0 however. Anyone has an idea why? I think it has something to do with "document.getElementsByTagName" (this gets html elements, not silverlight elements?) So I think I need to do something like this:

```
var textBlockArray = [];

function fillDataArray(sender) {
    textBlockArray = sender.getElementsByTagName("TextBlock");
}

function OnLoaded(sender) {
    alert('In Vowels');
    fillDataArray(sender);
}
```

But 'sender' doesn't have a method like that (and IntelliSense isn't helping me very much).

This is the xaml file:

http://pastebin.com/BR8bCJxh

The onLoaded event fires correctly, and the fillDataArray function also ends succesfully (tested this with an alert(textBlockArray.length) somewhere else)

Thanks.

Super short summary:

So, basicly, all I want to do is get ALL  elements from my Xaml page and put them into an array on the onLoad function.

Comment: Show the code where OnLoaded is called

Comment: added. see the pastebin link, line number 3

Comment: Yes, but what are you using to load? what is sender? It's the XAML string?

Comment: The debugger has learned me that sender is the root Grid object.

Comment: @Matthias: I believe this question relates to Silverlight 1, so I've added the silverlight-1.0 tag.  Can you please add this tag to all future questions you ask about it, to emphasise the fact that you're using (and stuck with) Silverlight 1.  Otherwise, answerers such as juandg will assume you're using a later version of Silverlight and hence provide answers which may be of little or no benefit to you.

Comment: @Matthias:  Seriously are you really using Silverlight-1.0, I very much doubt it.  The fact that your xaml includes a `Border` element would indicate that you are at least using a Silverlight-2.0 plugin. More likely the version of the plugin is 3 or 4 but that doesn't matter the point is you are (for reasons that are your own) you are using the "Javascript API for Silverlight".

Comment: The fact that a simple <Button /> doesn't work makes me suspect I'm using silverlight 1. But frankly, even our own teacher doesn't really know...

Comment: @Matthias: Oh dear that isn't good.  Why on earth would anyone want to actually teach the Javascript API to Silverlight at all.  BTW the Javascript API doesn't support the `Button`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980170(v=VS.95).aspx for a list of supported elements.  Not much has been added to the Javascript API after SL2, its primarly used to present a splash screen while the main XAP is loaded afterwhich the Managed application takes over.

Comment: I know it isn't good, we've been filing complains about this teaching method. But for the moment, we're stuck with old, rubbish technology :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really must stick with the Javascript API (I'm sure you have really good reason you aren't using the Managed API) then I would suggest you spend a little time reviewing the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903928%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

You cannot manipulate the Xaml as if it has some how become part of your html documents DOM.  The plugin handles the constructed set of Silverlight UI elements itself.

The Javascript API offers us no way to select out a simple collection of elements of a specific type.  In fact it offers no way to simply have a flat collection of all the elements.  We can create a javascript function to perform such an enumeration recursively on the basis that the only two elements that will contain other elements are a `Panel` or a `Border`.

Another issue is that the API it doesn't offer a good way to determine the type of an element either.  Hence its not obvious how we determine whether an element is a `Border`, a `Panel` or `TextBlock`.   However we could handle this by infering the type by testing the presence of a property that we would expect on that type (e.g., we expect a `Children` property on a `Panel).

Armed with all that we can start with an element enumerator:-

```
function forEachDescendant(elem, callBack)
{
    if (typeof elem.children == 'object')
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < elem.children.count; i++)
        {
            var child = elem.children.getItem(i);
            callBack(child);
            forEachDescendant(child, callBack);
        }
    }
    else if (typeof elem.child == 'object')
    {
        callBack(elem.child);
        forEachDescendant(elem.child, callBack);
    }
}
```

Now we can use this in the Grid's Loaded event.  I'm just going to add the string "XX" to the end of all the textblocks:-

```
var hasLoaded = false;
function OnLoaded(sender, eventArgs)
{
    if (hasLoaded == true)
        return;

    forEachDescendant(sender, function (elem)
    {
        if (typeof elem.Text == 'string')
        {
            elem.Text += 'XX';
        }
    });

    hasLoaded = true;
}
```

You'll not the `hasLoaded` protects the code from executing more than once.  Sometimes you can get loaded events more often that you would expect.

Comment: Thanks. That was a REALLY helpful and clear explanation. The code seems to be working as well.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has no access to your XAML, there's no way to manipulate you .NET objects from JavaScript.

This can be done with HTML because JavaScript has access to the HTML DOM of the page, but that's not the case with XAML object model, there's absolutely no connection, they run in very different contexts.

If it helps, the XAML does have access to the HTML model, so you could for instance call a JavaScript function from your XAML, but that also is a little tricky and is more a hack than a really solution, besides I'm not sure if that would solve your problem.

Comment: I regret to say, but this is incorrect. My onLoaded event fires correctly.. I also have 2 other Silverlight pages with perfectly working Javascript behind them. I just have some problems with this particular one.

Comment: from answering another of the OP's questions, I suspect he's using Silverlight 1.0, where there may well be JavaScript access.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this Grid object is about, but try something like this:

```
function fillDataArray(sender) {
    var textBlockArray = new Array(),i = 0,obj;
    while (sender[i]) {
        obj = sender[i];
        if (typeof obj=="TextBlock")
            textBlockArray.push(obj);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Show me this object's structure (like a print) and i can improve the code

Comment: I'm not really sure what this is supposed to do, but my textBlockArray still has a length of 0. (The result array does too by the way...)

Comment: show me the grid object on the debugger (print), with expanded nodes

Comment: How would I do that? I'm not used to using Javascript. (I'm using Visual Studio 2010 by the way.)

Comment: dont you see it in the debugger? just open the nodes and do a print screen and show the picture

Comment: Can't debug using Visual Studio, my breakpoints don't get hit for some reason. I can do basic debugging in Chrome, but when I put breakpoints there my Silverlight plugin crashes :p

Comment: have to be on the browser, firefox or chrome. even crashing you cant access the object?

Comment: then it becomes difficult to guess the internal structure of the object