# Controlling SilverLight application using selenium does not work

Tags: silverlight, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate an web application where in I am trying to control the silver light application.

I need to play pause and stop the player embedded in HTML.

There is an object tag which has an id for player.

I am trying to execute the JavaScript as follows

```
return document.getElementById('wptv_services_common_widgets_player_silverlight_PlayerObject_0').CurrentState
```

How ever I am not getting anything in return. What I get is just None as a result.

Similarly I also try to pause the player but I get different errors:

```
document.getElementById('wptv_services_common_widgets_player_silverlight_PlayerObject_0').Pause()
```

but i get

> error:  'document.getElementById(...).Pause is not a function'

If I edit the code to use with ' () ' then there is no error but nothing happens on the video ie. it does not pause.

**Note**: I got the link [How do I pause/play/seek a silverlight video using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175556/how-do-i-pause-play-seek-a-silverlight-video-using-javascript) and this is exactly what i want to achieve but the solution mentioned is not working for me.

I worked for youtube player and reference their API and similar functions were working just fine.

I am not familiar with silver-light application myself so a bit detailed information will be helpful.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight doesn't expose a DOM that is accessible to Selenium. If you have the sourcecode to the Silverlight application, you can expose specific functions to javascript host.

If you don't have source, you can use `TestStack.White` with Silverlight. Although it may be a bit clunky (because it works with standard accessibility that's built into Silverlight), it works.

For more information see https://github.com/TestStack/White